# How to distingush the meaning of comparative sentences

Tags: comparison, comparative-constructions, comparative

My apologize if the tittle is little confusing. So let's just focus on these couple examples:

1. I've never been on a bumpier plane ride.

> Options:
>
> a. The flight was bumpy
>
> b. The flight wasn't bumpy

**Attempt: I chose (a)**

2. I've never tasted hot chili peppers.

> Options:
>
> a. The peppers are hot.
>
> b. I haven't eaten hot chili peppers.

**Attempt: I chose (b)**

I've tried to check the key answers and those were correct. But, I doubt I can't answer the different problem surely without really understand how to distinguish whether **It has an affirmative answer** or **negative answer**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I've never tasted hot chili peppers* is a simple statement of fact.

*I've never been on a bumpier plane ride* means 'Of all the flights I've ever taken, this was the most bumpy'. The difference is that this sentence includes the *comparative* form of the adjective.

If you said *I've never been on a bumpy plane ride,* you would imply that your most recent one wasn't bumpy either.